# Passing some rows based on a threshold

Tags: awk

I am wondering how can I adapt the code (or add extra calls) below to pass some rows based on a threshold (here, a percentage value). My `xyz` file:

```
21.4    7
21.5    141
21.6    4
21.7    43
21.8    26
21.9    133
22      305
22.1    216
22.2    93
22.3    33
22.4    13
22.7    23
22.8    2
22.9    10
23      39
23.1    22
23.2    33
23.3    8
23.4    9
23.5    2
23.6    270
23.7    724
23.8    2349
23.9    2
24      1
24.1    11
24.2    376
24.3    1452
24.4    92
```

with the following `awk` call I obtain the corresponding percentage of the value in the 3rd column:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { s+=$2; next; } { printf "%s\t%s\t%s%%\n", $1, $2, 100*$2/s }' xyz xyz | sort -k3 -g
```

which gives:

```
24      1       0.0155304%
22.8    2       0.0310607%
23.5    2       0.0310607%
23.9    2       0.0310607%
21.6    4       0.0621214%
21.4    7       0.108713%
23.3    8       0.124243%
23.4    9       0.139773%
22.9    10      0.155304%
24.1    11      0.170834%
22.4    13      0.201895%
23.1    22      0.341668%
22.7    23      0.357198%
21.8    26      0.403789%
22.3    33      0.512502%
23.2    33      0.512502%
23      39      0.605684%
21.7    43      0.667806%
24.4    92      1.42879%
22.2    93      1.44432%
21.9    133     2.06554%
21.5    141     2.18978%
22.1    216     3.35456%
23.6    270     4.1932%
22      305     4.73676%
24.2    376     5.83942%
23.7    724     11.244%
24.3    1452    22.5501%
23.8    2349    36.4808%
```

So, I want to automagically filter the last Nth rows if the sum of the last values in the 3rd column is just greater than 60%, in the case above it will be `36.4808% + 22.5501% + 11.244% = 70.2749%`:

```
23.7    724     11.244%
24.3    1452    22.5501%
23.8    2349    36.4808%
```

Any hints are appreciated,

Comment: I mean the sum of the last values in the 3rd column, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You might want to change `100*$2/s` to `(s ? 100*$2/s : 0)` or similar to guard against the time when you run it and all `$2` values are `0` or the file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be done in a single `awk` command, but I think this version is shorter:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR { s+=$2; next; } { $3=100*$2/s "%" }1' xyz xyz |
sort -k3 -g |
awk '(t+=$3)>40'
```

prints out:

```
23.7    724     11.244%
24.3    1452    22.5501%
23.8    2349    36.4808%
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- for rows with duplicate values in the 2nd column, precendence goes to rows with a higher row number (via `awk/FNR`)

One `GNU awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN {OFS="\t" }

      { a[$2][FNR]=$1                                # [FNR] needed to distinguish between rows with duplicate values in 2nd column
        s+=$2
      }

END   { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"        # sort array by numeric index (descending order)
        for (i in a) {                               # loop through array (sorted by $2 descending)
            for (j in a[i]) {                        # loop through potential duplicate $2 values (sorted by FNR descending)
                pct=100*i/s                 
                out[--c]=a[i][j] OFS i OFS pct "%"   # build output line, store in out[] array, index= -1, -2, ...
                sum+=pct
                if (sum > 60) break                  # if the sum of percentages > 60 then break from loop
            }
            if (sum > 60) break                      # if the sum of percentages > 60 then break from loop
        }
        for (i=c;i<0;i++)                            # print contents of out[] array starting with lowest index and increasing to -1
            print out[i]
      }
' xyz
```

**NOTE:** requires `GNU awk` for:

- multidimensional arrays (aka array of arrays)
- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` support

This generates:

```
23.7    724     11.244%
24.3    1452    22.5501%
23.8    2349    36.4808%
```